# How to create list in Sharepoint online, where the cascade lookup actually works?

Tags: lookup, sharepoint-online, cascade

How to create list in Sharepoint online, where cascade lookup actually works?

I tried multiple solutions as jquery.js and some probably old ones, but it doesn't work.

```
</ContentTemplate>
</SharePoint:UIVersionedContent>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" `enter code here`src="https://leelsro.sharepoint.com/sites/SandBox/SiteAssets/jquery.SPServices.js"></script >

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns({
        relationshipList: "states",
        relationshipListParentColumn: "countries",
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",
        parentColumn: "countries",
        childColumn: "states",
        debug: true
    })
})
</script >
```

I need just simple cascade with countries and states.

Answer (score 1):

1.Create a Country list.

[image]

2.Create a states list and create a look up column from Country list.

[image]

3.Create a third list called test. Add two look up columns, column states from list states, column countries from list country.

4.In the new item page, add a Script Editor web part. Enter the below script.

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">  
$(document).ready(function ()  
{  
    $().SPServices.SPCascadeDropdowns(  
    {  
        relationshipList: "states",  
        relationshipListParentColumn: "countries",  
        relationshipListChildColumn: "Title",  
        parentColumn: "countries",  
        childColumn: "states",  
        debug: true  
    });   
});  
</script>
```

[image]

Test result:

[image]

To add Script Editor web part:

Click edit page in the new item page

[image]

Add web part:
[image]

Comment: thank you for response.. please can you describe how to add Script Editor web part?